# How to construct with E in java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

Can you help me how to fix the size ​​in the below code?
I tried using the usual methods with Object

```
public class DequeCyclic<E>{
    E[] queue;
    public DequeCyclic(int size) {
      DequeCyclic<E> queue = new DequeCyclic<E>(size);
    }
}
```

and `queue = new E[size]`

but it didn't work

Comment: This should lead to infinite object creation since you're calling the constructor inside  constructor

Comment: You cannot create an array of a generic type in Java, because of type erasure. Arrays and generics don't play nice together. Possible solution: Make the member `queue` something else than an array; make it a `List<E>` instead, for example.

Comment: I use generic array 
'queue = (E[]) new Object[size]; '
then it said
Note: __tester__.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.